# How can I write a cleaner code of the following array-formatting code?

Tags: javascript

About object arrays handle - javascript:

I have a projects array like:

```
// all projects

var projects = [{
  name: '', 
  company: 'c1',
  skills: ['s1', 's4']
}, {
  name: 'p2', 
  company: 'c2', 
  skills: ['s2']
}, {
  name: 'p3',
  company: 'c3',
  skills: ['s3']
}, {
  name: 'p4',
  company: 'c1',
  skills: ['s1', 's5']
}, {
  name: 'p5',
  company: 'c2',
  skills: ['s3']
}]
```

I want to collect each company's skills if the project has used in the company like (If p1 project uses s1 skill, then collect it.)

```
// results

var companySkills = [{
  company: 'c1',
  skills: ['s1', 's4', 's5']
}, {
  company: 'c2',
  skills: ['s2', 's3']
}, {
  company: 'c3',
  skills: ['s3']
}]
```

What I writing now:

```
    // what I writing now, I want to improve the code.
    var companySkills = []
    projects.forEach(project => {
      let each = {}
      const alreadyCompany = companySkills.find(companySkill => companySkill.company === project.company)
      if (!alreadyCompany) {
        each.company = project.company
        each.skills = []
      }
      project.skills.forEach(skill => {
        if (alreadyCompany) {
          alreadyCompany.skills = [skill, ...alreadyCompany.skills]
        } else {
          each.skills = [skill, ...each.skills]
        }
      })
      if (!alreadyCompany) {
        companySkills = [each, ...companySkills]
      }
    })

    // final results

    companySkills = companySkills.map(companySkill => ({
      company: companySkill.company,
      skills: [...new Set(companySkill.skills)]
    }))
```

Is there any better way to write the cleaner code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method with ES6 `Map` and then get values.

```js
var projects = [{"name":"","company":"c1","skills":["s1","s4"]},{"name":"p2","company":"c2","skills":["s2"]},{"name":"p3","company":"c3","skills":["s3"]},{"name":"p4","company":"c1","skills":["s5"]},{"name":"p5","company":"c2","skills":["s3"]}]

var result = projects.reduce((r, {company, skills}) => {
  if(!r.get(company)) r.set(company, {company, skills});
  else r.get(company).skills.push(...skills);
  return r;
}, new Map()).values()

console.log(Array.from(result))
```

To make skills unique without duplicate elements you can first make it a `Set` and then on last iteration you can transform it to arrays.

```js
var projects = [{"name":"","company":"c1","skills":["s1","s4"]},{"name":"p2","company":"c2","skills":["s2"]},{"name":"p3","company":"c3","skills":["s3"]},{"name":"p4","company":"c1","skills":["s1", "s1", "s5", "s5", "s1"]},{"name":"p5","company":"c2","skills":["s3"]}]

var result = projects.reduce((r, {company, skills}, i, arr) => {
  if(!r.get(company)) r.set(company, {company, skills: new Set(skills)});
  else skills.forEach(skill => r.get(company).skills.add(skill))
  if(!arr[i + 1]) r.forEach(p => p.skills = [...p.skills])
  return r;
}, new Map()).values()

console.log(Array.from(result))
```

Comment: "new Map" in the parameter will not pass the eslint, how to resolve it!?

Comment: Try `new Map()` maybe.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I found this solution can't work if the project have same skill. Like: if the p4 project have the s1 skill, it will dulpicate s1..

Comment: @KevinHu Take a look at update, skills should be array of unique values now.

Comment: Not works correctly. :( If p4 project has s1 skill, the result will not correct.

Comment: Based on your expected result my understanding was that you want to group them by `company` property.

Comment: I think the remove the duplicate skill solution is not correct. Add s1 to the project p4's skills, the result c1 company should have skills "s1, s4, s5"

Comment: You're welcome. The problem was spread syntax with add method, we have to use loop instead and add each element independently to Set.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest `reduce`ing into an object indexed by `company`, and then you can push to the `skills` array in the appropriate object in the accumulator (creating it first if necessary):

```js
const projects=[{name:'',company:'c1',skills:['s1','s4']},{name:'p2',company:'c2',skills:['s2']},{name:'p3',company:'c3',skills:['s3']},{name:'p4',company:'c1',skills:['s5']},{name:'p5',company:'c2',skills:['s3']}]

const companySkillsObj = projects.reduce((a, { company, skills }) => {
  if (!a[company]) a[company] = { company, skills: [] };
  a[company].skills.push(...skills);
  return a;
}, {});
const companySkills = Object.values(companySkillsObj);
console.log(companySkills);
```

If you want to avoid duplicate skills, then use a `Set` instead:

```js
var projects=[{name:'',company:'c1',skills:['s1','s4']},{name:'p2',company:'c2',skills:['s2']},{name:'p3',company:'c3',skills:['s3']},{name:'p4',company:'c1',skills:['s1','s5']},{name:'p5',company:'c2',skills:['s3']}];

const companySkillsObj = projects.reduce((a, { company, skills }) => {
  if (!a[company]) a[company] = new Set();
  skills.forEach(a[company].add, a[company]);
  return a;
}, {});
const companySkills = Object.entries(companySkillsObj)
  .map(([company, set]) => ({ company, skills: [...set] }));
console.log(companySkills);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I found this solution can't work if the project have same skill. Like: if the p4 project have the s1 skill, it will dulpicate s1..

Comment: You should post all the relevant requirements in the question *the first time you post it*. To avoid duplicating skills, use a `Set` instead, see edit.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers a different approach without Map and Set.

```js
const projects = [{
    name: '',
    company: 'c1',
    skills: ['s1', 's4']
}, {
    name: 'p2',
    company: 'c2',
    skills: ['s2']
}, {
    name: 'p3',
    company: 'c3',
    skills: ['s3']
}, {
    name: 'p4',
    company: 'c1',
    skills: ['s1', 's5']
}, {
    name: 'p5',
    company: 'c2',
    skills: ['s3']
}];

const groupProjects = (array) =>

    // Deconstruct and keep the properties we want
    
    array.reduce((acc, { company, skills }) => {
        
        // find if we already have added this company
        
        const index = acc.findIndex((a) => a.company === company);

        if (index === -1) return acc.concat(({ company, skills }));

        skills.forEach((skill) => {
            
            // add unique skills
            
            if (!acc[index].skills.includes(skill)) acc[index].skills.push(skill);
        });

        return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(groupProjects(projects));
```